# the meaning of "to be of scientific merit"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, phrases

> The cornerstone of the scientific method requires that your results, **to be of scientific merit**, must be reproducible.

What's the meaning of "to be of scientific merit"? Is it having any association with "to be honest" or something like that? Because I think they are quite similar, having the same structure of "to be adjective".

Comment: It means "to be scientifically valid" or "to be considered as properly scientific"

Answer (score 2):

"Scientific merit" means

> The degree. of quality that a research study possesses is scientific merit, and when it high it. contributes valuable, valid, and meaningful information that is justifiable, logical, and. consequential to scientific disciplines (Chen, Contreras, & Roberts, 2016). [Source](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/340444385_Scientific_Merit_Evaluation_and_Justification)

While to "be of scientific merit", means it has to follow the above requirement of "scientific merit".

More specifically in this context, it means that if something is to have **scientific merit**, it has to be **reproducible**.

Answer (score 1):

If your results are going **to be of scientific merit**, they have to be reproducible - that is, every time a similar experiment is done it has to produce the same result.

*To be honest* is just a parenthesis saying that the speaker is talking frankly. In your example, the *to be* phrase is an essential part of the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

> Definitions for Scientific

> (adjective) conforming with the principles or methods used in science
> (adjective) of or relating to the practice of science

> Definitions for Merit

> (noun) a quality that gives something special worth
> (noun) the relative usefulness or importance of something as judged by specific qualities

[synonym.tech](https://synonym.tech/phrase/scientific/merit)

'something is *to be of scientific merit*' hence means 'it must have been obtained from experiments/ researches done conforming with the principles or methods used in science'.

*to be of scientific merit* has nothing to do with *to be honest*, although they share the same structure.

> The cornerstone of the scientific method requires that your results, to be of scientific merit, must be reproducible.

hence means the results, obtained from experiments/ researches done conforming with the principles or methods used in science, must be consistent each time the same experiments/ researches are carried out under the same set of conditions.